# Place text and image in different line

Tags: css, tabs

I have a code like

```
<span ><img src="xxx.png">Tab1</span><span ><img src="yyy.png">Tab2</span>
```

This code creates two tab but the only problem is that tab1/tab2 and image xxx/yyy are in same line.I want them to be in different line and i want both span element in same line.
The tabs should look like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float:left property of css would be beneficial in doing your work

Answer (score 0):

You may be using the wrong element. `<span>` is use for inline content, whereas `<div>` may be better suited to what you're trying to do. You want them on a new line, but span is specifically created/used for non-line breaking items.

Try this:

```
<div><img src="xxx.png">Tab1</div><div><img src="yyy.png">Tab2</div>
```

More info on [What is the difference between HTML tags <div> and <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-div-and-span)

Comment: div will place both tabs in two lines and the image and text will still be in same line

Comment: That doesn't mean that your usage of `span` goes against its intended use. Your question is misleading/confusing to the reader. Edit your question to CLEARLY state what effect you want. Include a screenshot/mockup if necessary. From what I read, you wanted 2 tabs (consisting of an img and text) on 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

I take the markup for granted:

```
img { display: block; }
span { float: left; }
```

Comment: If you can set the image's width it would be a better solution to use this rule: img { display: block; width: 20px; margin: 0 auto; }