# Inner difference Between Span & Div Tags

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between HTML tags DIV and SPAN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-div-and-span)

I'd like to know the difference between using `<span>` and `<div>` when writing a one line text other than the div is a block styling container while a span doesn't leave a space after it.

Is there something related to text-overflow that we should use span for it ? 
I'm searching for other differences but I can't find.

Answer (score 2):

From a styling perspective, `<span>` defaults to `display: inline` and `<div>` defaults to `display: block`. There are no other CSS differences.

(They have different rules for what elements may be contained by them, and what elements may contain them, but that is unrelated to CSS).

Comment: Do you know where can I find about "what elements may be contained by them, and what elements may contain them" ?

Comment: @OnlyHope: Take a look at the duplicate question from the comments above, the accepted answer is quite thorough.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_and_div#Differences_and_default_behavior):

> There is one difference between div and span. In standard HTML, a div
>   is a block-level element whereas a span is an inline element. The div
>   block visually isolates a section of a document on the page, in the
>   same way as a paragraph. The span element contains a piece of
>   information inline with the surrounding text. In practice, even this
>   feature can be changed by the use of Cascading Style Sheets (CSS).

Sorry to burst your bubble looking for something more special.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the block level vs. inline level property of these elements *is* the major difference between the two.

What you should consider is what else besides text is going to be in each.  It's perfectly valid to put inline elements as well as other block elements *in* a block element, however it is only valid to put other inline elements *in* inline elements.

More reading here: http://www.w3resource.com/html/HTML-block-level-and-inline-elements.php

As far as which to use for writing a "one line text", I would probably use neither.  A paragraph, or `<p>`, tag seems best suited for that.  Semantically, a paragraph tag is used to display a paragraph of text, whereas a `<div>` is semantically used to display a block of *something*... paragraphs, lists, images, forms, etc.  Meanwhile, a `<span>` is semantically used to display something that doesn't quite fit into another element.  Maybe you have a paragraph and want to apply some special formatting to just one part of a sentence, for example... a `<span>` would be a good way to do that.

Answer (score -2):

`<span>` has no block properties, thus there is no line break at the end, whereas a unmodified(default block element) `<div>` tag is a block element and will include a line break at the end of the div tag.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp

Comment: Mmh... "no line break at the end"/"line break at the end" isn't an accurate depiction of `inline` versus `block` display.

Comment: It's a web developer's HUMAN answer -- and yes, block elements all have line breaks at the end. <div>test1</div>test2 will apear as two separate lines, whereas <span>test1</span>test2 will appear on one line.

Comment: It is a very incomplete description of the differences between block and inline styling. W3Schools is not a good choice of reference either.

Comment: That's not the only difference and not necessarily the difference, either. And I see you've added links to w3schools. They're not an authoritative reference on... anything. See: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Have you even bothered to look at the contents of those references? I am not vouching their website, but the content inside. Show me what's wrong in those references before posting it as obsolete.

Comment: The very statement "Note: By default, browsers always place a line break before and after the <div> element. However, this can be changed with CSS." is wrong. And I'm not saying it's obsolete, either. It was wrong to begin with.

Comment: So you're saying that statement you quoted is incorrect? An unmodified <div> is always considered a block element, placing a break before and after the tag. How is that wrong?

Comment: @BenAshton: Because it does not place a line break. It is not a line break. That is incorrect terminology. It's not necessarily before and after, either; consider margin collapse. Besides, there is no such thing as an "unmodified" `<div>`.