# placing <button> tag inside <span> tag is right way of placement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have requirement where i need to display text and button in one box.
i have placed button tag inside span which has text  and button

```
  inside span tag
  +-------------------+
  | text here         |
  |                   |    
  | <button> tag here |
  +-------------------+
```

my question is the right approach having button inside span. as just learned span is inline element and it can have only text, images etc..

[What is the difference between HTML tags <div> and <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-div-and-span)

Comment: i have list of boxes, where i have toggle button, like invite/ignore functionality for each person boxes

Comment: You can't place a block element inside a span (or any inline element), but a button is an inline element and can be places inside a span, so yes, that is the right approach if you're looking for an inline element containing text and another inline element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can of course use CSS to render the span as a block element, or even an inline-block if that is what you need.

```
.yourSpanClass {
    display: block;
}

.yourSpanClass {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Though, i'd advice you to simply use a div if you have access to the HTML.

Supported browsers: `http://caniuse.com/inline-block`

Comment: The button element is indeed rendered as inline. This was just an example if he needed to render the span as a block element.

Comment: IE support inline-block element, but you can use it only with block elements. With inline elements you need css hack: 
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
zoom: 1;

Answer (score -6):

Drop the button. Use CSS/jQuery to make the span a button. Don't forget to style :hover and use JS/jQ to do the intended action

Comment: The semantics are all mixed up here, a span is a span - a button is a button.

Comment: says who? He needed a span inside a button

Comment: `Use CSS/jQuery to make the span a button`. It's a bad idea to style and define elements in a way that mimics other elements. If the span needs to be a button - it should be a button element. I could style a span to mimic a H1, doesn't mean it should be. It's a pain to comply with semantics - but it's worth it. Accessibility for one - how would a visually-impaired user has access to the ability to interact with an element if that element type is typically just used for static content?