# What is the difference between a DIV with display: inline-block and a SPAN

Tags: html, css

What is the difference between a DIV with display: inline-block and a SPAN ?

Simalarly, between a SPAN with display: block and a DIV.

Comment: `span` default display is inline not inline-block.

Comment: Googling `What is the difference between a DIV with display: inline-block and a SPAN` seems to yield relevant results?

Comment: But SO is so much more fun.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between HTML tags DIV and SPAN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-div-and-span)

Comment: I'd love to know why my answer was downvoted.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is a duplicate of that specific question, as this one queries specifically the `inline-block` and `inline` display attributes. There probably is a similar question somewhere though.

Answer (score 1):

There will only be a semantic difference per se between the two, given the correct styles, both will probably display the same.

However, some browsers may or may not display correctly. Also, you can't nest block elements in spans, that is invalid HTML, and may cause some browsers to choke or display incorrectly.

Divs are block elements, spans are inline elements. Don't do that is the bottom line, it will make things messed up.

Also, spans have the style `display:inline`, not `display:inline-block`

Comment: downvoted only because there is certainly a difference between the two

Answer (score 1):

From the [W3 Specification:](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display)

> **inline-block** 
>   This value causes an element to generate an inline-level block container. The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box, and the element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box.
>
> **inline** 
>   This value causes an element to generate one or more inline boxes.

You can see how they differ visually [here](http://dustwell.com/div-span-inline-block.html).

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, a span, by default is display:inline.

According to w3schools, the difference between display:inline and display:inline-block is

- An inline element has no line break before or after it, and it
  tolerates HTML elements next to it.

  A block element has some whitespace above and below it and does not
  tolerate any HTML elements next to it.

  An inline-block element is placed as an inline element (on the same
  line as adjacent content), but it behaves as a block element.