# How do I position divs next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a simple admin console consisting of 3 divs. One div (usersearch) extends to the entire width of the page whilst the 2 remaining divs (privset, privrules) must be next to each other 50:50.

Upon loading the page, only one div shows whilst the other is pushed somewhere else.

```
<style>
body {
padding:0%;
margin:0%;
overflow: hidden;
}

header {
background-color:black;
color:white;
text-align:center;
padding:5px; 
}

#usersearch {

border-bottom: medium solid;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 40vh;
}
#privset{

border-right: medium solid;
position: relative;
width: 50vw;
height: 100vh;

}

#privrules{
float:right;
position: relative;
width: 50vw;
height: 100vh;


}

footer {
background-color:black;
color:white;
clear:both;
text-align:center;
padding:5px;
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
}
</style>
```

HTML below

```
<div id="usersearch">Customer Information</div>
<div id="privset">Priv set</div>
<div id="privrules">Priv rules</div>
```

Comment: two divs next to each other says "span" to me

Comment: Spans can't contain block-level content, so that would be quite a limitation.

Comment: Yep, just pointing it out given the presented "text only" div set in the question. Reference; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-div-and-span and the element semantics in the specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#elements

Answer (score 0):

the css border you were using takes up a pixel or 2, so setting each one to

```
width: 50vh;
```

width was too much. either set them to 49vh or get rid of the border.

also, if you want 2 divs floated next to each other, set

```
float: left;
```

for both of the divs.

working example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/cDv2d9ln8yfUkSGVHDKV?p=preview)

Comment: glad i could help. please mark this as the answer if you're satisfied.

Comment: Done. I don't have the privileges to make my up-vote visible at this point. I assume it'll appear as some point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to float the `#privset` div and adjust for box-sizing.

Also, using 50vw can cause issues as broswers have different intepretations of the whether any scrollbar is included in the overall width. Use 50% instead for cross-browser support.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#usersearch {
  border-bottom: medium solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vh;
}
#privset {
  border-right: medium solid;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
}
#privrules {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="usersearch">Customer Information</div>
<div id="privset">Priv set</div>
<div id="privrules">Priv rules</div>
```

Comment: Floats cause problems in many cases. Inline-block is a better first choice.

Comment: Flex woud be better but I'm going with the OPs decision....and inline block has just as many issues as float.

Answer (score 0):

All elements sitting side by side should be floated. Additionally, if you're using borders and/or padding, `box-sizing: border-box` should be set.

See this working example: https://jsfiddle.net/lewster32/3zb7xgh2/