# HTML: Text:align property working with span or with a tag

Tags: html

I tried the below code  wherein I wanted to center a link , I dont know why these 2 below piece of code didnt work

```
Code1:

<span class="my-class">
  <a href="http://www.example.com">example</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</span>​

Code2:

  <a href="http://www.example.com" style="text-align:center">example</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

The piece of code which worked was:
<div class="my-class">
  <a href="http://www.example.com">example</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</div>​
```

Could you please tell me why the above 2 codes didnt work?

Comment: Post your CSS rule `my-class` too

Comment: It's because `<div>` has `display:block` by default. `<span>` is `display:inline`. `block` and `inline` render differently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between HTML tags <div> and <span>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-div-and-span)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first doesn't because the anchor `a` is inside an inline element, which just grow to its content's size, and their parent, the body, does not have the property `text-align: center` set.

The second doesn't because its parent, in this case the body, need to have the rule `text-align: center`

The third **does** because the `my-class` most likely has the `text-align` property set to `center`, and as a div is a block element it spawn the full width of its parent, in this case the body, hence the anchor will center inside it.

So, to center an inline (and inline-block) element, its parent need the property`text-align: center` set, and to center a block element, like a div, it has to have a width, less wide than its parent, and its margin's left/right set to `auto`.

Sample

```css
.centered-span {
  text-align: center;
}

.centered-div {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<span class="centered-span">Hey there (not centered)</span>

<div class="centered-span">
  <span>Hey there - span</span>
<div>
  
<div class="centered-div">Hey there - div</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`span` and `a` elements do not behavior as blocking element because they are supposed to be used inline. You either will need to set it by setting up a display and width attribute or wrapping it around a parent. Instead, you could use a `ul>li>a` hierarchy and set their attributes properly.

```css
.aBox {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}


.notBox {
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span class="aBox">
  <a href="#">Hey, it's a link</a>
</span>

<span class="notBox">
  <a href="#">Hey, it's a link</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

A span element is an in-line element which is only as wide as its content.  Whereas a div element is a block level element and will be as wide as the page or its containing div.

When using the `text-align: center;' property, you must place it on the element containing the element that you want to center.