# overflow-x text-overflow in span

Tags: html, css

```
 .whysolong {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Put in `div`

```
<div class="whysolong">So many people here but only 3 or four global apps grow UP?</div>
```

OK!

So many people here....

and `span`

```
<span class="whysolong">So many people here but only 3 or four global apps grow UP?</span>
```

> Still showing full text..

So many people here but only 3 or four global apps grow UP?

Why?

Comment: Why what? Your whole question is unclear.

Comment: @curt please scroll down before add a comment.

Comment: answers aren't displayed during the review of questions in triage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Text overflow can only happen on block or inline-block level elements, because the element needs to have a width in order to be overflow-ed. The overflow happens in the direction as determined by the [direction property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp) or related attributes.

```css
 .whysolong {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 154px;
}

 .whysolongblock {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 154px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="whysolong">So many people here but only 3 or four global apps grow UP?</div>
<span class="whysolong">So many people here but only 3 or four global apps grow UP?</span>
<div class="whysolongblock">So many people here but only 3 or four global apps grow UP?</div>
<span class="whysolongblock">So many people here but only 3 or four global apps grow UP?</span>
```

**Note:** `text-overflow` only occurs when the container's overflow property has the value `hidden`, `scroll` or `auto` and `white-space: nowrap;`.

Comment: I just set  `width` and `display:inline-block` thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Property `text-overflow` applies to block container elements only. A `<span>` element is inline element by default, therefore it doesn't support this attribute. To make `<span>` support `text-overflow` you need to define it as block-level element:

```
span {
    display: block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

span has to have either block or inline-block display because otherwise it's just an inline element.

Answer (score 0):

Exists a differences between DIV and SPAN because one is a Block Element and other is a Inline Element.

You can see:
[What is the difference between HTML tags <div> and <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-div-and-span)

http://cssreset.com/understanding-the-difference-between-div-and-span/