# jquery load html content (datestamp) into div not going where I want

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a separate file called lastrun.html that simply contains a datestamp.  I want that to display in my index.html in the right spot.

I am using

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#lastrun").load("lastrun.html");
 });
```

and then in my html body section I have:

```
<p>Last run on <div id="lastrun" style="display:inline"></div></p>
```

The expectation was:

Last run on June 05 2017, but instead it does:

Last run

June 05 2017

How do I get the date to appaer on the Last run line?

Comment: Inspect the HTML of the page and paste the result instead of plain text please

Comment: any reason you are loading it from another page?

Answer (score 2):

Change div to span

```
<p>Last run on <span id="lastrun" ></span></p>
```

For a better explanation of difference between div and span you check out [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-div-and-span)

Comment: got my vote as it is a correct solution, but it would be better if you posted an explanation of why that would work and why the original does not.

Answer (score 1):

`div` is not allowed inside a `p`. This causes the `p` to close, followed by the `div` and then another empty `p`.

So your html, even before the ajax call, is rendered by the browsers like this

```
<p>Last run on </p>
<div id="lastrun" style="display:inline"></div>
<p></p>
```

---

So you need to either use an allowed element inside the `p`, like a `span` or use a `div` for the outer element instead of the `p`.

```
<p>Last run on <span id="lastrun" style="display:inline"></span></p>
```

or

```
<div>Last run on <div id="lastrun" style="display:inline"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [jsfiddle with 2 techniques](https://jsfiddle.net/maxbilbow/zm5tf7re/3/) for loading content.

```
$("#lastrun").load('lastrun.html');
```

The above is identical to your example. The div tags shouldn't affect this however you be able to debug with a more traditional ajax request:

```
$.get('lastrun.html', function(aResponse) {
  $("#lastrun").html(aResponse);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.error(arguments);
  $("#lastrun").html(errorThrown);
});
```

This should help you determine whether there is a problem with the request url itself.