# Understanding Div and Span

Tags: html, css

They themselves don't do anything, they are just used alongside a selector to target particular code so they can be styled with CSS.

Am I correct on this? Maybe there is more meaning to them at a higher level

Comment: `div` -> `block`   `span` -> `inline`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a duplicate question. You can find discussion at [What is the difference between HTML tags <div> and <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-div-and-span)

It is really well explained there and you will get awesome information related both HTML tags.