# HTML Why is there difference between span and div in my border?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently learning CSS and I am experimenting and I stumbled upon this difference in the output. 
So this is the code:

```
        <html>
    <body>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .red-text {
        color: red;
      }

      h2 {
        font-family: Lobster, monospace;
      }

      p {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: monospace;
      }

      .smaller-image {
        width: 100px;
      }

      .thick-green-border {
        border-width: 10px;
        border-color: green;
        border-style: solid;

      }
    </style>

    <h2 class="red-text">CatPhotoApp</h2>
    <main>
      <p class="red-text">Click here to view more <a href="#">cat photos</a>. 
      </p>

      <a href="#"><div class="thick-green-border"><img class="smaller-image" 
      src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on 
      its back."></div></a>
    </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the output:
[image]

However if I change this line:

```
 <a href="#"><div class="thick-green-border"><img class="smaller-image" 
  src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on 
  its back."></div></a>
```

to this(just replacing the div with span):

```
 <a href="#"><span class="thick-green-border"><img class="smaller-image" 
  src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on 
  its back."></span></a>
```

I get totally different output:
[image]

So can anybody explain me what's going on in the code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/183536/6191987

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between HTML tags <div> and <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-div-and-span)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is about `display` style**

`div` is `display:block` by default: whats mean it `width:100%`

→ that the reason `border` is in all the `width`

`span` is `display: inline` by default whats mean only necessary `width`

→ that the reason `border` is in `width` that `span` needs

Learn more here:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp
See here:

```css
div,span{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>I take 100% of width the prove for it is background-color</div>
<span>I take width as my content prove for it is background-color</span>
```

Comment: tell me for more explaination

Comment: So span is kind of fixed and one cannot overwrite it's width. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I write `by default`--- you can set width or eve set `display:block` to `span`

Answer (score 3):

The `<div>` tag is a block-level element so it takes entire block. but `<span>` tag is a inline element.

```html
<div>0000000<div>111111</div>222222</div>
```

```html
<span>0000000<span>111111</span>222222</span>
```

Check this example for clarification.

if i add `display:block` to span it behaves like a block. so it takes full width

```css
span{display:block;border:1px solid green}
```

```html
<span>0000000<span>111111</span>222222</span>
```

Comment: I know that div is block-level and span is inline. But the span is supposed to work the way the div works because img is inline too,

Comment: here you have applied border to 'div' not to image.
because you applied border to block element it shows properties of block element

Comment: That's what I did. I know that when I apply the border to div it will work. But the question is why it doesn't work with the span? The img is within the span.

Comment: because its not a block level element just use display: block and border to span you can get the correct result

Answer (score 0):

The basic difference between `<div>` and `<span>` is that `<div>` takes the 100% of the width available whereas `<span>` is going to take the width that is required by the element inside it. We can also say that `<div>` is a `block` element and `<span>` is an `inline`. element