# Text next-to image

Tags: html, css

Just with CSS, I would like to put the number of subscribers next to the logo

But with 
`position : absolute` the logo is on the text
and if the text is in

`float : right` there are a problems

My program

```
<div>
    <h3>Suivez-nous</h3>
    <div class="Facebook">
        <img src="images/Facebook.png">
        <p>500 000 abonnés</p>
    </div>
    <div class="twitter">
        <img src="images/twitter.png">
    </div>
    <div class="instagram">
        <img src="images/instagram.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

All code in https://codepen.io/adri1212/pen/dgVVpK

**This code is a just part of a footer and use a flexbox**

Comment: Can't you just not use a `<p>` tag? Seems unnecessary here.

Comment: But I use a flexbox, beacause this code it's juste one part of a footer

Comment: That seems like important information to have in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between HTML tags <div> and <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-div-and-span)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, `<p>` need to be removed, and the `<div>` elements need to be replaced with `<span>`

This will give you a single line of images with text between the images:

```
<footer>
    <div>
        <h3>Titre section 1</h3>
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Titre section 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Titre section 3</h3>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h3>Suivez-nous</h3>
        <span class="Facebook">
            <img src="images/Facebook.png">
            500 000 abonnés
        </span>
        <span class="twitter">
            <img src="images/twitter.png">
        </span>
        <span class="instagram">
            <img src="images/instagram.png">
        </span>
        </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use `<p>` as its default display is block

[Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JmrrLZ)

If you want to wrap your text - you can use `<span>` which is an inline element by default.

[Example with span and margin](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmooxE)

Comment: Yes, but after I don't move the text. For exemple put the text at 20px

Comment: You can add `margin-left: 20px` to the `<span>` container

Comment: it's all span to move, so logo + text and not just the text

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution,

In the CSS I put

```
    .Facebook > p{
         display : inline;
    }
```

Comment: Probably a better solution might be wrapping it under a div and then `display: flex, flexDirection: row`

Comment: Okay, it's functional but not valid.

Comment: I think to use flex-direction but the other people I found solution so it's goob

Comment: Agree that this will work, but you would do better using a different tag that already displays inline (such as `<span>`) and simply adjust the margins. One of the whole points of using `<p>` is that it is a block level element, and this changes all that.

Comment: Yes I use the solution <span> (my previous message may not have been understood correctly )