# <span> vs <div> vs <Fragment>

Tags: html, reactjs, web

I got confused about the listed elements.

What I already know is:

1. They all don't have real meanings.
2. Fragment is not a real element.

Can you explain what are the key differences between them? When should we choose one over the other?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span A span and a div are very similar, however a span defaults to display inline where a div is display block. You can change them with CSS, but that’s the default.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-div-and-span; Fragment doesn't appear in the DOM at all, see https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about `<fragment>` but can tell about differences of `<div>` and `<span>`.

The difference between `<span>` and `<div>` is that a `<span>` element is in-line and usually used for a small chunk of HTML inside a line (such as inside a paragraph), whereas a `<div>` (division) element is block-line (which is basically equivalent to having a line-break before and after it) and used to group larger chunks of code.

`<div>` example:

```html
<div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:20px;">
  <h2>London</h2>
  <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
</div>
```

`<span>` example:

```html
<h1>My <span style="color:red">Important</span> Heading</h1>
```

A final example is when you use

```html
<div>Hello</div>
<div>World</div>
```

that gives this:

> Hello
>   World

`<div>` gives a new line between each because it is a block-level element, whereas `<span>` doesn't:

```html
<span>Hello</span>
<span>World</span>
```

> Hello World