# Regex - extract substrings starts and ends with specific patterns (HTML parsing)?

Tags: html, regex

I am parsing some well-organized strings(HTML format) to extract data. The Format is like(newline added for reading convinience):

```
<span><h2>Category 1</h2>
<p><strong><u>Entry 1</u></strong></p>
<ul><li>Some Data</li></ul>
<h2>Category 2</h2>
<p><strong><u>Entry 2</span>
<ul><li>Some Data</li></ul>
</span>
```

I intend to find all strings between `<h2>` and extract strings after `</h2>` first. The searching pattern is `/<h2>Tier.*?<\/h2>(.*?)(<h2>|<\/span>)/g`. But each matching substring is exactly ending with `<h2>`. So the next category will not be extracted, while the third category block is fine because there is a new searching.

Then I try to search for substrings which not contains `<g2>` greedily. The pattern is  `h2>Category.*?<\/h2>(^(h2).)*`. It does not work though.

Comment: Where is "Tier" text in your HTML code???

Comment: Copied wrong strings, edited.

Comment: Use beautifulsoup.

Answer (score 1):

Try extract by this regex:

```
<h2>\K[^<]+
```

[Here Is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k16AoN/1)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clearly and makes me so confused.

But I think you want this:

```
<h2>[^<]+<\/h2>(.+?<\/ul>)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/k16AoN/2

Beside of that, you should refer this: [What is the difference between HTML tags <div> and <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-div-and-span). Maybe you use wrong `<span>` tag