# Confused about the effect of a line break in html

Tags: html, css, layout, line-breaks, spacing

I was under the impression that hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> to add a **line break** in my text editor (for the sole purpose of keeping my code tidy/easy to read), has "no effect" on the rendered output.

***Apparently I was mistaken.***  The example in the snippet below clearly shows that my line breaks are adding unwanted spacing after a `<span>`.

- I tried `box-sizing:border-box` but it has no effect (presumably since there are no borders).
- Negative margins seem to fix the problem, but that doesn't seem like a reasonable solution everywhere I want to add a line break to keep my code tidy.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to avoid this, or should I just code on one really long line from now on?

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20vh;
  width: 10vw;
  background-color: red;
}

span:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<span></span><span></span><span></span>
<span></span><span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
<span></span><span></span><span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
```

Comment: setting position `inline-block` on elements takes whitespace into account so returning to a new line in your editor will reflect in the browser, do the `span` elements need to be `inline-block`?

Comment: to add more complexity you have two spaces: the horizontal one created by whitespace and vertical one created by baseline alignment (added two duplicate)

Comment: Looking back at this, I think my confusion came down to being that my original understanding of `<span>` vs `<div>` was fundamentally flawed.  Going back to the [basics](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_and_div) for a [refresher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/183532/8112776) was helpful.  :-)