# Why does the top margin of one element affect another element when using spans?

Tags: html, css

Please see the HTML code below:

```css
#search
{
    display:inline;
    margin:100px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <span class="child">
        <input type="text" name="submit" id="submit">
    </span>
    
    <span class="child">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search">   
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

If I change the two span elements to divs then I see this:

[image]

The div result (second screenshot) is what I would expect, however it involves nesting an inline element (input) inside a block level element (div), which I believe is illegal.

Why does the top margin of one element (id of: search) also affect another element (id of: submit) when using spans?

I have spent a few hours Googling this and understanding the difference between spans and divs, however I have not found an answer.  There was another question on here similar with a comment from someone that just said: "collapse it".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between HTML tags <div> and <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-div-and-span)

Comment: the keyword is *baseline alignment*

Comment: @MaxiGui please don't make useless edits like so. Check if the code runs in the debug window. I'm not talking specific to this question, but to other ones you have edited. I'll delete this if you confirm that you hear me :).

Comment: @10Rep ok you can delete this message too

Answer (score 2):

`span` is an "inline level" element, while `div` is a "block level" element.

In terms of HTML, "block level" means that, the element will take full available width of the viewport of browser.

So, in your case, when you use `<span>` and you make one of them a 100px higher, because of `margin` property, the browser aligns another element to the current baseline (basically, it means vertical alignment to the bottom of "text line"). You can play with [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property on both `span`'s to see the effect.

When you use `<div>`, the browser makes each div on its separate line and as such second `div` gets margined without affecting the first one.

Btw, if you'll set `display: inline` to `div` tag you will get the same results as for `span`'s

Comment: Thanks.  I don't understand your last sentence.  Do you mean set a property of the div tag to display:inline?

Comment: @w0051977, do `div { display: inline }` in your `styles.css`