Show the value of a variable inside a string of text
I'm trying to display the following sentence in my site that is made of a static part and a dynamic one that depends on the value of a js variable
There are {X} things in the set

I'm using alpine.js and I'm aware of the x-text attribute. So I know that I could do
<div x-data="{n: 4}">
There are <div x-text="n"></div> things in the set
</div>

However when I do that there are two line-break around the  middle <div> https://jsfiddle.net/xws9qvmz/
Is there a way to properly do what I want ?
Either by using some form of templating like
<div x-data="{n: 4}">
There are $n things in the set
</div>

Or maybe by using something else than a div as the node to hold x-text="n" ?

use a span (inline) instead of a div (block)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-div-and-span-elements

That works !  thanks @pthomson
